# Cannot sign into Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-account

When I start, there is a popup saying that the evaluation period has finished. I simply need to sign into visual studio, but when I try I get this error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio We could not refresh the credentials for the account Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http, Version-4.0.0.0, Culture-neutral, PublickeyToken-bo3f5f7f11d50a3a or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

followed by:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

I am on version 15.8.0. Needless to say this is a total disaster as it completely blocks further development.

Edit: I should say that this is a continuation of this [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560743/nuget-package-manager-in-visual-studio-unable-to-load-the-service-index-for-sou), which started happening after the last windows update. I have just done another windows update, and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 3):

Run Visual Studio 2017

1. Before the sign in dialogue comes up quickly select `Tools` -> `Options`
2. Go to `Environment` -> `Accounts`
3. Select `Enable device code flow when adding or re-authenticating an account`
4. Click `OK`
5. Login through a browser

Comment: I had to try few times, it didnt seem to work with Firefox nor Edge, but it finally logged in using Chrome. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Windows, which fixed the problem (no surprises there).