# Your license has gone stale and must be updated. Check for an updated license to continue using this product. - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Though I have valid visual studio subscription, I am getting the below error:

[image]

I tried to reenter the credentials. After entering the credential, it is not pointing to the right page.

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: Is "gone stale" the same as "expired"?

Comment: yes, you can use the last comment of mine to resolve the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I have a valid visual studio subscription, I followed the following steps and validated myself for VS 2017:

1. Log in to the link: https://my.visualstudio.com/ProductKeys with visual studio subscription credentials.
2. Search for Visual Studio Professional 2017, Claim the license and copy it
3. Click on "Unlock with a Product Key" and apply the license.

That's it. License validation successful. I am using the VS 2017.

Comment: And if the little message "unlock with license key" isn't there?   MS expects you to keep tithing to them for eternity??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an active directory issue based on the error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-device-remediation

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio 2017

```
1. Before the sign in dialogue comes up quickly select Tools -> Options
2. Go to Environment -> Accounts
3. Select "Enable device code flow when adding or re-authenticating an account"
4. Click OK
5. Login through a browser
```

Visual studio will give you a link to follow and a code to authenticate. When you follow the link, you simply enter the code and everything is fixed.

You may have to close and re-open Visual Studio.

[Cannot sign into Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809275/cannot-sign-into-visual-studio-2017)